Distribute Sales evenly across quarters, without exceeding the total
Have a list of yearly sales for a set of products, which I need to distribute evenly across quarters without exceeding the maximum of sales and using whole numbers.
Been trying for hours to make this work without any success.
Please see an example below of what I am trying to do:


Using one single dynamic array formula:


=SORT(QUOTIENT(C3,4)+(MOD(C3,4)>=SEQUENCE(,4)),,,1)


Without LAMBDA() iteration to spill:
=LET(α, C3:C14, δ, 4, INT(α/δ)+(SEQUENCE(,δ,δ,-1)<=MOD(α,δ)))



E3:
=TRUNC(C3/4,0):

F3:
=TRUNC((C3-E3)/3,0)

G3:
=TRUNC((C3-E3-F3)/2,0)

H3:
=C3-E3-F3-G3

Result:

